# Movendo peça, acrescenta novo tabuleiro de jogo

Tags: javascript, html, array

Bom dia, Estou com um pequeno problema na elaboração de um jogo de tabuleiro.
Quando tento mover uma peça, devolvendo um novo quadro(array de arrays), esta é adicionado à página em vez se substituir. Fico assim com dois e três quadros de acordo com as jogadas que fizer.

O meu código é o seguinte:

```js
"use strict"
function main() {

 var sGame = startGame(8, 4, 3)


 createGrid(sGame)
 //document.getElementById("game").innerHTML = tableOfGame; //passar para o html

 var UP1 = document.getElementById("UP1");
 UP1.onclick = function () {
  sGame = moveUp(sGame, 'P1');
  createGrid(sGame)

 }

 var Down1 = document.getElementById("Down1");
 Down1.onclick = function () {
  sGame = moveDown(sGame, 'P1');
  createGrid(sGame)
 }

 var Left1 = document.getElementById("Left1");
 Left1.onclick = function () {
  sGame = moveLeft(sGame, 'P1');
  createGrid(sGame)
 }

 var Right1 = document.getElementById("Right1");
 Right1.onclick = function () {
  sGame = moveRight(sGame, 'P1');
  createGrid(sGame)
 }
}


function createTurtleBoard(boardSize) {
 let tabuleiro = [boardSize];
 for (let row = 0; row < boardSize; row++) {
  tabuleiro[row] = [boardSize];
  for (let column = 0; column < boardSize; column++) {
   tabuleiro[row][column] = 0;
   //playerPosition.addEventListener('click', movePlayer, false)
  }
 }
 return tabuleiro;
}

function jewelsInsert(tableOfGame) {
 let rowA = (tableOfGame.length) / 2;
 let rowB = (tableOfGame.length) / 2 - 1;
 let columnA = (tableOfGame.length) / 2;
 let columnB = (tableOfGame.length) / 2 - 1;
 tableOfGame[rowA][columnA] = 'J';
 tableOfGame[rowB][columnB] = 'J';
 tableOfGame[rowA][columnB] = 'J';
 tableOfGame[rowB][columnA] = 'J';
 return tableOfGame
}

/*
*
*
*
*/
function addPlayers(tableOfGame, numPlayers) {
 let position = tableOfGame.length - 1;
 switch (numPlayers) {
  case 1:
   tableOfGame[0][0] = 'P1';
   break;
  case 2:
   tableOfGame[0][0] = 'P1';
   tableOfGame[position][0] = 'P2';
   break;
  case 3:
   tableOfGame[0][0] = 'P1';
   tableOfGame[position][0] = 'P2';
   tableOfGame[position][position] = 'P3';
   break;
  default:
   tableOfGame[2][2] = 'P1';
   tableOfGame[position][0] = 'P2';
   tableOfGame[position][position] = 'P3';
   tableOfGame[0][position] = 'P4';
   break;
 }
 return tableOfGame
}


function wallInsert(tableOfGame, numWall) {
 let size = tableOfGame.length - 1;
 let count = 0;
 while (count < numWall) {
  let column = Math.floor((Math.random() * size))
  let row = Math.floor((Math.random() * size))
  if (tableOfGame[row][column] === 0) {
   tableOfGame[row][column] = 'W'
   count++
  }
 }
 return tableOfGame
}


function startGame(boardSize, numPlayers, numWall) {
 let board = createTurtleBoard(boardSize);
 board = jewelsInsert(board);
 board = addPlayers(board, numPlayers);
 board = wallInsert(board, numWall);

 return board;

}


function playerFinder(tableOfGame, player) {
 let len = tableOfGame.length;
 for (let row = 0; row <= len; row++) {
  for (let column = 0; column <= len; column++) {
   if (tableOfGame[row][column] == player) {
    return [row, column];
   }
  }
 }
}

function isItAllowed(tableOfGame, player, tag) {
 let pl = playerFinder(tableOfGame, player)
 let row = pl[0];
 let column = pl[1];

 if (tag = "mUp") {
  if (row == 0 || tableOfGame[row - 1][column] == "p1" || tableOfGame[row - 1][column] == "p2" || tableOfGame[row - 1][column] == "p3" || tableOfGame[row - 1][column] == "p4" || tableOfGame[row - 1][column] == "w") {
   return false;
  }
  else { return true }
 }

 else if (tag = "mDw") {
  if (row == tableOfGame.length - 1 || tableOfGame[row + 1][column] == "p1" || tableOfGame[row + 1][column] == "p2" || tableOfGame[row + 1][column] == "p3" || tableOfGame[row + 1][column] == "p4" || tableOfGame[row + 1][column] == "w") {
   return false;
  }
  else { return true }
 }

 else if (tag = "mLf") {
  if (column == 0 || tableOfGame[row][column - 1] == "p1" || tableOfGame[row][column - 1] == "p2" || tableOfGame[row][column - 1] == "p3" || tableOfGame[row][column - 1] == "p4" || tableOfGame[row][column - 1] == "w") {
   return false;
  }
  else { return true }
 }

 else if (tag = "mRt") {
  if (column == tableOfGame.length - 1 || tableOfGame[row][column + 1] == "p1" || tableOfGame[row][column + 1] == "p2" || tableOfGame[row][column + 1] == "p3" || tableOfGame[row][column + 1] == "p4" || tableOfGame[row][column + 1] == "w") {
   return false;
  }
  else { return true }
 }
}



function moveUp(tableOfGame, player) {
 var table = tableOfGame;
 let pl = playerFinder(table, player)
 let row = pl[0];
 let column = pl[1];
 console.log("pos" + table[row][column])
 let control = isItAllowed(table, player, "mUp")
 console.log("control" + control)
 if (control == true) {
  var n = table.length
  table[row][column] = 0;
  table[row - 1][column] = player;

 }
 return table
}

function moveDown(tableOfGame, player) {
 var table = tableOfGame;
 let pl = playerFinder(table, player)
 let row = pl[0];
 let column = pl[1];
 console.log("pos" + table[row][column])
 let control = isItAllowed(table, player, "mDw")
 console.log("control" + control)
 if (control == true) {
  var n = table.length
  table[row][column] = 0;
  table[row + 1][column] = player;

 }
 return table
}

function moveLeft(tableOfGame, player) {
 var table = tableOfGame;
 let pl = playerFinder(table, player)
 let row = pl[0];
 let column = pl[1];
 console.log("pos" + table[row][column])
 let control = isItAllowed(table, player, "mLf")
 console.log("control" + control)
 if (control == true) {
  var n = table.length
  table[row][column] = 0;
  table[row][column - 1] = player;

 }
 return table
}

function moveRight(tableOfGame, player) {
 var table = tableOfGame;
 let pl = playerFinder(table, player)
 let row = pl[0];
 let column = pl[1];
 console.log("pos" + table[row][column])
 let control = isItAllowed(table, player, "mRt")
 console.log("control" + control)
 if (control == true) {
  var n = table.length
  table[row][column] = 0;
  table[row][column + 1] = player;

 }
 return table
}



function createGrid(tableOfGame) {
 var y = document.getElementById("gridOfGame");
 var n = tableOfGame.length;
 for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  var tablerow = document.createElement("tr");
  var tableData;
  for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
   tableData = document.createElement("td");
   tableData.innerHTML = (tableOfGame[i][j]);
   tablerow.appendChild(tableData);
  }
  y.appendChild(tablerow);
 }
}

function delRow() {
 let x = tableOfGame.length;
 for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  function moveUp() {
   document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(i);
  }
 }
}



document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) { main() });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/CSS" href="style.css">-->

  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="position.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Play</title>
</head>

<body>

  

  <img class="Home" src="RT-Banner-Cópia.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
  <audio autoplay>

    <source src="music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
  </audio>

  <h2 class="Home1 Login"><a href="Login.html">Login</a></h2>
  <h2 class="Home2"><a href="Regras.html">Como Jogar</a></h2>
  <h2 class="Home3"><a href="Pontuações.html">Classificação</a></h2>
  <h2 class="Home4"><a href="Historia.html">História</a></h2>
  <h2 class="Home5 Login"><a href="Registo.html">Registar</a></h2>
  <header>
    <h1>Game</h1>
    <table id="gridOfGame">

    </table>
    <button id='UP1'>UP</button>
 <button id = 'Left1'>Left</button><button id = 'Right1'>Right</button>
 <button id = "Down1">Down</button>
    <p id="game"></p>

  </header>
<h5><a href="Home.html">Início</a></h5>
  <!-- <script id ="js" src="game.js"></script>-->
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Carregando numa direção qualquer o 'P1' vai mudar de posição, mas vai duplicar o quadro.

Como faço para não o fazer e me devolver o quadro alterado só?

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Acredito que está duplicando pois a cada interação você faz a chamada novamente do método de criação. Logo acredito que uma alternativa é "limpar" a #gridOfGame antes de recriar a tabela, pesquise sobre remover elementos com javascript. Ou seja, em sua função de createGrid(tableOfGame) faça alguma maneira para limpar <table id="gridOfGame">. Se você utilizar o inspecionador de elementos do seu navegador para entender melhor o fluxo. Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esvazie a div que recebe a tabela antes de fazer o `appendChild` colocando:

```
y.innerHTML = '';
```

Após:

```
var y = document.getElementById("gridOfGame");
```

Na função `createGrid`.